# Parsing JSON of format Map<String, ArrayList<String>> in android

Tags: android, json

I am having JSON object of this format :

> {"1":["1","test.txt","authortest","sizetest"],"2":["2","GraphTheory.pdf","testing","0"]}

It is Map> listMap;

Now I need to parse it in here :

As of given answer parsing is done like this :

```
  protected Map<String,ArrayList<String>> doInBackground(
            String... arg0) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.getType();
        Map<String,ArrayList<String>> allBookList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        return allBookList;
}
```

Here each Mapping contains an arraylist with three items : BOOKNAME,BOOKAUTHOR and BOOKSIZE.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ViewLibrary.this, result,
                R.layout.book_item, new String[] { BOOKNAME,
                        BOOKAUTHOR,BOOKSIZE }, new int[] { R.id.bookname,
                        R.id.bookauthor, R.id.booksize });

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now i need to display it in a listview.How to do this ?
I think adapter need to be set in onPostExecute method.But I am not able to understand it how.As from where to get these three : BOOKNAME,
                            BOOKAUTHOR,BOOKSIZE

Comment: It is not working? What happens?

Comment: @Salem I am new user of JSON.So I dont know how to parse it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are new to JSON you may want to use GSON library. TO do that add to yuor dependencies in build.gradle and sync

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

Supposing `json` contains your JSON string you can use it like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

// (...)

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, List<String>> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: What to import for using Type ?

Comment: One more question,Suppose we need to set each of the mapped value to a list item with ids : "bookname","bookauthor" and "booksize" how to do it ?

Comment: Can you give an example? Generally you would replace `List<String>` with `List<SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` is a class with public fields with the same names of your JSON fields

Comment: I am saying say for present Activity we have xml which have a listview and other xml named list_item with the 3 fields : "bookname","bookauthor" and "booksize".Now I want the results obtained to be displayed in list view

Comment: What should be adapter for this ?I am asking for that adapter that need to be set to this listview

Comment: You should post that as another question.

Comment: I think It would be better to finish this question here only

Comment: Also As i can post one que in 90 minutes it wont be possible to post different que.So can you help me here ?

Comment: I already gave you my opinion. Nothing good comes from a super question with sub-questions in it. Also there are already plenty of questions and tutorials on how to create custom listview adapters ([example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html))

Comment: I edited the post .Am almost done.But just last problem that i edited .See if you can help