# JSONArray to POJO

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a Json string like this :

```
[{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"},{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"},{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"},{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"}]
```

I'm new at this. How can I parse this JSONArray to POJO ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27080027/1205368). You will have to change the POJO definition but the idea is the same.

Comment: By the way I'm using jackson.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Parsers are objects used to tokenize JSON content into tokens and associated data. It is the lowest level of read access to JSON content.

Most common way to create parsers is from external sources (Files, HTTP request streams) or buffered data (Strings, byte arrays / buffers). For this purpose org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory has extensive set of methods to construct parsers, such as:

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory(); // or, for data binding, org.codehaus.jackson.mapper.MappingJsonFactory 
JsonParser jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(file); // or URL, Stream, Reader, String, byte[]
```

Also, if you happen to have an `ObjectMapper`, there is also `ObjectMapper.getJsonFactory()` that you can use to reuse factory it has (since (re)using a `JsonFactory` instances is one Performance Best Practices).

But you can also create parsers from alternate sources:

Starting with version 1.3, you can read contents of root `JsonNode` (see Tree Model) by `JsonParser jp = node.traverse()`
Starting with version 1.5 you can buffer underlying JSON tokens into `org.codehaus.jackson.util.TokenBuffer`, and later on create JsonParser to read content (for replaying streams).
Reading JSON tokens from these sources is significantly more efficient than re-parsing JSON content from textual representation.

It's very easy and simple. Try this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBkuLu-ycEc
and you can read more about jackson from the link below
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi

Comment: Please give a bit more information on how to use Jackson and not only provide a link.

Comment: actually this link will give you a clear idea about jackson and how it works step by step

Comment: I know, but this is not how StackOverflow wants to see answers. Please read the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. It clearly says: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link."

Comment: No problem, I can see you are a new user. It is good that you want to help others. Please expand your answer a bit and the downvote will disappear.